# Varnish inadvertedly caching pages from logged in users and serving them to everyone else

Tags: nginx, magento-1.7, varnish

We use varnish + nginx to serve magento web shops. Sessions are stored in Redis databases.

Sometimes i notice that varnish caches pages from logged in users and serves them to everyone else, which is awful. We use the phoenix magento plugin, magento 1.7.0.2, and the vcl below.

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for PageCache powered by Varnish for Magento module.

# default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
  .host = "localhost";
  .port = "XXX";
}

# admin backend with longer timeout values. Set this to the same IP & port as your default server.
backend admin {
  .host = "localhost";
  .port = "XXX";
  .first_byte_timeout = 18000s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 18000s;
}

# add your Magento server IP to allow purges from the backend
acl purge {
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}

import std;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
            req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }

    if (req.request != "GET" &&
        req.request != "HEAD" &&
        req.request != "PUT" &&
        req.request != "POST" &&
        req.request != "TRACE" &&
        req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.request != "DELETE" &&
        req.request != "PURGE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    # purge request
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        ban("obj.http.X-Purge-Host ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Host + " && obj.http.X-Purge-URL ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Regex + " && obj.http.Content-Type ~ " + req.http.X-Purge-Content-Type);
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }

    # switch to admin backend configuration
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "adminhtml=") {
        set req.backend = admin;
    }

    # we only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://[^/]+", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
    if (req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$") {
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # not cacheable by default
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Https) {
        return (pass);
    }

    # do not cache any page from index files
    if (req.url ~ "^/(index)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # as soon as we have a NO_CACHE cookie pass request
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # remove Google gclid parameters
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    if (req.http.cookie ~ "PAGECACHE_ENV=") {
        set req.http.pageCacheEnv = regsub(
            req.http.cookie,
            "(.*)PAGECACHE_ENV=([^;]*)(.*)",
            "\2"
        );
        hash_data(req.http.pageCacheEnv);
        remove req.http.pageCacheEnv;
    }

    if (!(req.url ~ "^/(media|js|skin)/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|swf|ico)$")) {
        call design_exception;
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.status == 500) {
       set beresp.saintmode = 10s;
       return (restart);
    }
    set beresp.grace = 5m;

    # enable ESI feature if needed
    if (beresp.http.X-Cache-DoEsi == "1") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    # add ban-lurker tags to object
    set beresp.http.X-Purge-URL = req.url;
    set beresp.http.X-Purge-Host = req.http.host;

    if (beresp.status == 200 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 404) {
        if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html" || beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/xml") {
            if ((beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") || (beresp.ttl < 1s)) {
                set beresp.ttl = 0s;
                return (hit_for_pass);
            }

            # marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age:
            set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";

            # Don't cache cookies
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        } else {
            # set default TTL value for static content
            set beresp.ttl = 4h;
        }
        return (deliver);
    }

    return (hit_for_pass);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # debug info
    if (resp.http.X-Cache-Debug) {
        if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
            set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;
        } else {
           set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
        }
        set resp.http.X-Cache-Expires = resp.http.Expires;
    } else {
        # remove Varnish/proxy header
        remove resp.http.X-Varnish;
        remove resp.http.Via;
        remove resp.http.Age;
        remove resp.http.X-Purge-URL;
        remove resp.http.X-Purge-Host;
    }

    if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
        # Remove the magic marker
        unset resp.http.magicmarker;

        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "Mon, 31 Mar 2008 10:00:00 GMT";
        set resp.http.Age = "0";
    }
}

sub design_exception {
}
```

Any ideas why this happens? As far as I know, the code below should prevent that from happening:

```
if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
    return (pass);
}
```

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: do you actually set this `NO_CACHE` cookie ?

Comment: yes, the Phoenix_PageCache modules does it on the method below: sanitizeCacheControlHeader()
    {
        $cookie = self::getCookie();
        if ($cookie->get(self::NO_CACHE_COOKIE) || $cookie->get(self::MESSAGE_NO_CACHE_COOKIE)) {
            self::setNoCacheHeader();
        }
    }

Comment: ok so another question, does the app only show other people's data, or do they actually become logged in as those other people?
also are the cached people admins on your system? or other random people ?

Comment: Hey. It caches random people data and they are not logged in, they only sometimes see some random people names on the page headers (and only sometimes, it doesn't always happen). They are not site admins, as the admin area is not cached up at all. thanks again!

Comment: I just noticed that this is most likely to be occurring when the cookie is set while the user is on https urls. Maybe Varnish is not being able to find the cookie?

Comment: wish i could say i had a clue

Answer (score 0):

A fast fix for now would be replacing

```
if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=")
```

with

```
if (req.http.cookie) {
```

or just delete the whole block, it should be handled by the default vcl, unless you have a `return` that would prevent varnish from reaching it's handler's code